# Error install Sentry in Laravel 5.3 following the official guide

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, sentry

I have an error installing sentry in laravel 5.3 following the official guide. Someone knows why this error.
Thank you very much and excuse my English.

```
$ composer require sentry/sentry-laravel:1.0.0-beta3 \
php-http/curl-client guzzlehttp/psr7

Error   
Problem 1
    - Installation request for sentry/sentry-laravel 1.0.0-beta3 ->
satisfiable by sentry/sentry-laravel[1.0.0-beta3].
    - sentry/sentry-laravel 1.0.0-beta3 requires sentry/sentry 2.0.0-beta1 -> 
satisfiable by sentry/sentry[2.0.0-beta1] but these conflict with your requirements
or minimum-stability.
```

Comment: If your laravel version is 5.x, you can try just doing `composer require sentry/sentry-laravel` without explicitely specifying 1.0.0-beta3 version

Answer (score 1):

you need to add these two lines to your `composer.json` file:

```
"minimum-stability": "beta",
"prefer-stable": true
```

We will soon drop the beta tag, then this issue should be gone.